# Настройки Hibernate C3P0

Tags: hibernate, java, c3p0, sql

```
<!--как только переполнится пул коннектов, укажем, сколько соединений ещё добавить в пул-->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">2</property>

<!--как долго ждать, чтобы подтвердить соединение, т.е. не закрывать его, а, например, сделать запрос "select 1"-->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>

<!--максимальное количество соединений в пуле-->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>

<!--минимальный размер пула-->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">4</property>

<!--таймаут для с3p0-->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">320</property>

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">3</property>
```

1. Объясните пожалуйста последний пункт.
2. Если много коннектов, то открываются много соединений к БД, которые не закрываются вообще, в чем проблема?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Гугл помог: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=353736&seqNum=4 Сори, невнимательно прочитал вопрос и ответил на предпоследний, хотя и то, и то есть в таблице по ссылке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. hibernate.c3p0.max_statements   - размер кэша стейтментов.. вероятно, речь идёт о prepared statement'ах
2. Не закрываются вообще? В смысле, вообще никогда? По идее, после таймаута какие-то могут закрыться. С другой стороны, вас это не должно волновать. Главное, чтобы вы в своём приложении освобождали соединения (возвращали в пул).

Comment: соединения не освобождаются, видимо что-то в настройках не так как нужно.
Хочу, чтобы
1. По умолчанию висело 2 коннекта к базе
Первый юзер посылает запрос в приложение, юзает 1 коннект. Второй... приложение смотрит, ага.. первый занят, юзаем второй. Третий юзер появляется, оба коннекта заняты, создаём ещё 2 и добавляем в пул... и т.д. В конце концов у меня получется куча коннектов к базе, которые не закрываются по таймауту.

Comment: Так может это потому, что клиентский код не освобождает соединения (не возвращает в пул), вот пул их и не обрывает, а думает, что они заняты.

Comment: Нет, не из-за этого. 100% в настройке c3p0, только где...

Answer (score 1):

> hibernate.c3p0.max_statements - размер кэша стейтментов... вероятно, речь идёт о prepared statement'ах

Подскажите, что здесь понимается под стейтментом? Я меняю значение между 20 и 5000 и разницы не вижу (виснет раз в час). Везде пишут, что max_statements - это максимальное количество стейтментов, а как они создаются, копятся, очищаются не понятно.